# Implementation of a N-ary tree in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers, binary-tree

I have an assignment about creating a N-ary tree, in which I need to create a tree from a text file and traverse it in different ways. I have completed the homework but with a binary tree version and now i got stuck with the N-ary tree version about which container I should use. How can i easily change my binary implementation to a N-ary one?

Comment: Why the -2?  It would be better if you had stated what I shoud add, the code or whatever, instead of just giving a -

Comment: I think they downvoted because they expect you to show what you have down so far. See [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The uni has a cheating pollicy, and i figured if i posted the code it would be too risky.

Comment: First, I don't think you need to post all the code, try to solve it, and when you have a real problem you can ask a detailed question. Second, I don't think asking for advice is cheating, but if you are not sure, just ask you professor for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary tree usually has two hard-coded links:  left subtree and right subtree.

An N-ary tree would need to support N amount of subtree links.  If the N amount is fixed, you could use an array of links.  Otherwise use an `std::vector` of links.

Search the internet for "C++ BTree example".